# Android Studio проблемы с proguard

Tags: android, proguard, ndk

Перешел с `Android Studio 2.3` на `Android Studio 3.2` и начались конкретные проблемы с `proguard`.
Имеется приложение с нативным кодом

```
public class Main extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Utils.setListener(new Utils.OnListener() {
@Override
public void onListener() {
//Обработчик
}
});
}
}
```

И в `gradle`

```
ndk {
abiFilters "x86","x86_64","armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a"
}
```

По началу приложение просто крашилось долго искал и выяснил что либы `.so` для моей архитектуры просто не компилировались в `apk`.Так и сейчас вместо 4 указанных выше в `apk` добавляются только 2.После приложение крашилось с ошибкой `Failed to register native method`,опять искал долго и оказалось что класс `Utils` и имена нативных методов переименовываются прогуардом, запретил переименовывать, но приложение не работает так как не срабатывает `onListener`,выяснил что из класса `Main`, `onListener` перекидывается в класс с произвольным именем.И все классы дробятся и создаются в 2 раза больше чем их на самом деле.Без прогуарда все работает, а на `Android Studio 2.3` с прогуардом все работает.

```
Уже устал неделю по 10 часов в день сидеть и компилировать одно приложение
1.Почему не добавляются все нативные библиотеки в apk и как сделать что бы они все добавлялись?
2.Куда девается onListener и почему он не хочет работать?
Есть возможность скомпилировать с прогуардом рабочее приложение на Android Studio 3.2?
```

Comment: Уже 4.х и 2020.х были и прошли, 2021.х уже два месяца как, а вы только на 3.2 переходите, которая вышла 3,5 года назад. Кто же что вспомнит уже о ней?

Comment: Вопрос в другом

Comment: А может как раз в этом - если на 2.3 работало, а на 3.2 нет. В чём для вас её преимущество, что вы перешли именно на эту версию? В любом случае в вопросе не достаточно контекста для решения проблемы - показывайте ваш gradle и proguard скрипты и что там за листенер - как и откуда он должен вызываться.

Comment: @woesss перешёл потому что для внешних библиотек нужна java8 в target/source compatibility. Код написал выше и да же с ним такие косяки.Все написано как и откуда он вызывается. Или если будет с другого места вызываться прогуард его не будет переносить в новый класс удаляя из класса активити?

Comment: Вопрос как раз в этом, Proguard уже прошлое Android разработки. `When you build your project using Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 or higher, the plugin no longer uses ProGuard to perform compile-time code optimization. Instead, the plugin works with the R8 compiler to handle the following compile-time tasks.` https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: AS 3.4 вышла в апреле 2019, думаю не многие из здесь присутствующих помнят что за проблемы были с ProGuard или все еще его используют.

Comment: Classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0', а гредл 4.6. сколько только не гуглил информации такой по прогуарду не было, да видел в прогуард добавить правила для v8. Это полный пипец, эти идиоты вечно проблем подкинут. Мне сейчас что делать что бы запутать имена классов и удалить ненужный код?у меня ПК старый, на нем не работают новые версии, ошибка на ошибки и экран гаснет.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос с работай прогуарда решен, как оказалось с папки проекта исчезла папка build в которой был дефолтный конфиг прогуард.Я не понимаю почему студия не намекала что данной папки нет.Но вопрос с компиляцией apk под все abi не решен, по прежнему создается только с одним abi.